# What is the bracha on "Kit Kat" bars?

Tags: mezonot-beracha, shehakol-beracha, ikkar-tafel

I'm using Kit Kats as an example of any chocolate covered wafer. I'm not sure what is considered *ikar* - the main purpose of the food. Is it the wafer which requires *mezonot* or the chocolate covering which requires *shehakol*?

Or should one make a bracha on both? If so, I gather that generally, *mezonot* would come before *shehakol*. If so, how does one practically do this if the chocolate is on the outside? Does he have to scrape away some of the chocolate and eat the wafer first?

Comment: Moderators, esp. - note the newly added tag. If it's inappropriate, or there is a similar tag, inform me.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://www.berachot.org/halacha/26_Bracha_on_Snack_Bars.html

Comment: @ezra I know about that site, and I checked for something there. The page that you linked to isn't useful for answering this question. I am quite certain that most opinions say that regarding an ice cream sandwhich, one needs to make both brachot. I can't locate that info, but Kit Kats MIGHT have similar reasoning to that.

Comment: Depends on the quantity of wafer. If it is light and only used as a support to the rest, it is sheakol. If it is meaningful then it is mezonot. For instance, in Israel poskim write the bracha for Kit Kat is mezonot, on "Pesek zman" (similar to Kit Kat with more chocolate/less wafer) it is sheakol

Comment: @mbloch The answer, below, seems comprehensive, and I think that the analogy to the chocolate covered raisins is correct. The wafer in the Kit Kat is quite thick, so if it weren't for it being dipped in chocolate, there's no question of the mezonot. I think in this situation, it may not be quite as much of an ikar / tafel in terms of quantity, but rather, it's "purpose". Is it a wafer or a candy / chocolate bar? I think that this answer would apply equally to peanut M & M's.

Comment: @DanF the analogy is not good because mezonot has a *hashivut* (importance) that raisins don't have. With the raisins, you can go after what you like best. When mezonot is involved it is not as simple.

Comment: @mbloch Yes, that's true. However, doesn't the "purpose" of the food count. E.g. - most poskim state that when eating an Oreo, even though it's a cookie, if one eats the cookie & the "goop" separately, one makes separate brachot. I think w/ a Kit Kat, it may be similar. Seems people like the chocolate covering and the wafer equally. Also, unless you scrape off the chocolate, that's what you're eating first.

Comment: It is interesting why would you ask such a question on this site? Is there something in this Machlokes you don't know? I could expect it from a newcomer, but from you? What kind of discussion you expect on this subject?

Comment: @AlBerko There were several ideas that I wasn't certain about. Even when I think I am sure about something, I'm open to reading another angle. Occasionally, I ask questions to just elicit a discussion on the topic so that the public can learn from it. I don't always ask questions just for my own knowledge. I think that's part of the attitude and benefits of a forum such as this. We don't just ask for ourselves - we ask so that others can benefit from our questions, as well. There's nothing wrong with shared reserarch and discovery.

Comment: @DanF There's a big problem with this kind of discussion, and especially marking an answer as "accepted", as I understand that the site's policy is not to provide the final Halokho you're asking for. So if you'd phrase it like "what are the different considerations for saying either Sheakol or Mezoynos on KitKat" that seems acceptable, but asking for an Halokho when you know it is a serious disput - I don't think it is acceptable, otherwise, we can put every Makhlokes here and start discussing it over the internet.

Comment: @DanF Another problem you (and others) absolutely ignore is the differences in Shitoys. You try to present Judaism as having one branch of accepted American Rabbies e.g. R' Moyshe. But others don't follow R' Moshe, I personally was close to an Israeli Rabbi R' Shlomo Shlezinger that opposed R' Moyshe in many ways. Many members are Chassidic and follow their traditions. But the readers don't understand that distinction. So it is a bit of לפני עוור. So I suggest we all (scholars I mean) refrain from posing questions "What is the true Halakha of X", but phrase it more mildly, as I proposed.

Comment: @AlBerko Your issue has its merits and it's something to discuss as a question on Meta, rather than here. However, I think that the site disclaimer that says that you should consult with your own rav is sufficient for this forum. As for how that's understood or obeyed by readers - that's an entirely different question, and I don't think its our job, here, to poll people on that. Personally, as I mentioned, I view the accepted answer as good analysis to my question. We're not a Yom Tov post mincha halachic shitta discussion lecture, here.

Comment: @AlBerko All "accepted" voting means here is that OP likes that as being the best answer, for him / her personally. It is not any endorsement of what s/he or others plan to do or should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a machlokes based on what is your preference as well as what is considered the ikar and tafel in the product as well as the majority.

This seems to be analogous to the case of Rav Moshe Feinstein discussing what bracha to make on chocolate covered raisins.

[A Sweet Bracha What Bracha Does One Recite over Chocolate-Covered Raisins?](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=6500)

> In Rav Moshe’s tshuvah, he addresses the following issue: When eating
>   a food composed of items with different brachos, we must determine
>   which food is the more important part, the ikar, and determines the
>   bracha of the entire food. Rav Moshe deliberates whether the chocolate
>   or the raisin is more important in order to determine whether the
>   bracha on chocolate-covered raisins is Ha’eitz, like the raisin, or
>   Shehakol, like the chocolate. Rav Moshe concludes that neither the
>   chocolate nor the raisins can be considered of secondary importance
>   (tafeil) to the other, and therefore chocolate-covered raisins require
>   two brachos, Ha’eitz on the raisins and Shehakol on the chocolate.
>
> Rav Moshe then discusses which of the two brachos to recite first.
>   Usually, one should recite the bracha of Ha’eitz before reciting
>   Shehakol. However, Rav Moshe points out that one must eat the
>   chocolate before reaching the raisin; thus, the bracha on the
>   chocolate will have to be first. Rav Moshe concludes that the best
>   thing to do is to recite Ha’eitz on a regular raisin and then Shehakol
>   on the chocolate. (When this option does not exist, he paskins that
>   one should recite Shehakol on the chocolate and then Ha’eitz on the
>   raisin.)

The way that I read this is to make the *shehakol* immediately followed by *haeitz* (in the case of a raisin) or *mezonos* (in the case of the Twix or Kit Kat bar) and then eat the two simultaneously.

There are other ways of handling the matter.

For example, [OU Guide to Blessings](https://oukosher.org/guide-to-blessings/#desserts) cited at [Brachot 38 – Which blessing on a twix?] says that one **can** make the shehacol first deliberately excluding the wafer part and then making mezonos to include the wafer. After this eat the two together without a hefsek. This is similar to Rav Moshe's psak, but he does not appear to require that one explicitly excludes the wafer (or the raisin) from the shehakol.

> If you eat a candy bar containing fruit, nuts, wafers, or other
>   fillings because you specifically want to eat the filling, you should
>   say only the appropriate brachah for the filling. If, however, the
>   chocolate itself is just as important to you, first say Shehakol for
>   the chocolate (bearing in mind that you do not intend to include the
>   filling in this brachah), and then the appropriate brachah for the
>   filling (Igrot Moshe, Orach Chaim 3:31).
>
> This does not apply in the
>   case of wafers, since the chocolate is always considered a subordinate
>   ingredient in a candy bar with wafers, and therefore, only Mezonot
>   need be said (Mishnah Berurah, Orach Chaim 168:27).

[Bracha on chocolate with wafer](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3101) says that it is really indeterminate.

> **Question:** If a chocolate seems to consist mainly of wafer (eg kif-kef or Kit-Kat) should one say "Mezonot?" I assume that if there
>   is doubt concerning whether there is more chocolate or wafer one
>   should say "Shehakol"?
>
> **Answer:** Though there is not universal agreement on this point, it seems the most common positions that if the majority is chocolate, it
>   is "Shehakol" and if the majority is wafer it is "Mezonot". Some hold
>   that since we eat the wafer for the chocolate and the wafer is just to
>   hold it together, it is always "Shehakol" while others argue that the
>   wafer also tastes good (sometimes) and therefore the rule that
>   "Mezonot" is dominant even when it is not the majority should apply.

It appears that the advice given in the first location cited is to say

> As far as I can tell – there is no consensus. You could take the easy
>   route and not eat such chocolate bars/cakes ever again chas veshalom
>   or weigh up the above positions and decide for yourself. Maybe even
>   ask your Rabbi what he does!

Comment: Good find! As for asking my rabbi, I can pretty much anticipate his answer - "I don't know. Why don't you wash and make hamotzi and eat the KIt Kat as part of the se'udah?"

Comment: I could post this as a separate question if you prefer, but since a Shehakol can cover almost *anything* couldn't one just intend for it to cover both the chocolate and the wafer (or raisin), not specifically excluding it like the second source states?

Comment: @DanF ...And then your anticipated answer would be something like, "But I don't want to have to say the whole Birkas HaMazon for just a Kit Kat..." ;-)

Comment: @Mike However, the *shehakol* covers other matters only *bediavad*. The question on what one **should** do is *lechatchilah*

Comment: Based particularly on the base topic / link in this answer, I assume that the same rule would apply to the bracha on peanut M & M's, What do you think?

Comment: @Danf sounds logical